# Why has the number of European space launches dropped in 2018?

Tags: launch, esa

There is a table of space launches from wikipedia in [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_in_spaceflight#By_country) *(Images have been updated on July 11, 2018)*:[image]
For now about half of year has been passed, but share of ESA launches is comparable with share of New Zealand.
 For comparison, in [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_in_spaceflight#By_country) it was 9 European space launches. 
[image]
I look a [list](http://www.esa.int/For_Media/Launch_schedule_2018) of ESA launches for 2018. There are 2-4 launches with european launch-vehicle remaind for this year. What is going on with european space program?

---

To @uhon comment.
It is possible to find older statistics with link

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_in_spaceflight#By_country

You just need to change year at this link.

Comment: "What is going on with european space program?" It continues ahead with probes, satellites etc, but uses cheaper launchers than Arianne, which is a very expensive heavy-lift rocket with a rather narrow range of applications.

Comment: There isn't enough data here to even see if this is significant statistically. Can you give ten or twenty years of data, then do a test to see if this difference is meaningful?

Comment: My guess: If it is real, it is SpaceX. Arianne space used to be the defacto launcher of large GEO satellites, now SpaceX is starting to fill that roll.

Comment: The list on the ESA site only shows European institutional launches (ESA's own missions, EC for Galileo, etc), it doesn't include commercial payloads on Ariane 5 (which is most Ariane 5 launches).

Comment: Using the `@username` works in comments and sometimes in chat, but not in question or answer posts, so the `@uhoh` in your question didn't generate a notification for me. A good response to my comment would be for you to *add more data to your question*, rather than to *tell me where to go* (to look for it).

Comment: Also recall there was an [Ariane 5 mishap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_flight_VA241) in late Jaunary, which likely pushed everything back for several months.

Comment: @user71659 That was my first thought as well, but when I looked up the dates, the next flight was only 10 weeks later (5 April) which is a fairly typical gap for a launcher that flies about 6 times per year. That's now 14 weeks ago, and will be almost 16 weeks if the next flight takes place on 25 July as currently planned.

Answer (score 5):

Those stats look incomplete.

From the [Arianespace launch schedule for this year](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=6114.1380) (as compiled by a NasaSpaceflight forum member):

- 3 launches so far (this is fewer than expected, launch cadence is usually around 1/month)
- 16 more planned (which could be more than they can launch in a year, given the minimum time between launches they have)

Comment: Thanks for the list (+1). One of three performed launches in your list was actually a Russian Soyuz launch from Kourou. So, in my list it  was a Russian launch. There were two European launches (Ariane 5) and one of them partial failed. So, the only successful European launch was performed. That was the reason I ask this question. Anyway, I hope you are right and ESA will make enough of launches till the end of the year. (By the way, 4 launches for august doesn't sound realistic for me)

Comment: @Loom, "NET" means "No Earlier Than"